# Not reading data and executing a function that does not exist

Tags: node.js, express, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I'm building an API prototype and I have code that reads data from a Google Sheets (serving as a CMS) but the problem is when calling the route that I defined in Express.js it is not reading data from the sheet. It works for sheet 1 but not for sheet 2.
To read the data I use this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet

Link to a copy of the Google Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yx0iRPPho2H1OGrvTAspkTr2b1zwzbkxeb7hRuqqNwc/edit?usp=sharing

Relevant Code:

```
router.get('/getallcontent', async function (req, res) {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('sheetId');
        await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
            client_email: creds.client_email,
            private_key: creds.private_key
        });
        const info = await doc.loadInfo();
        const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1];
        
        const rows = await sheet.getRows()

        // console.log(rows)
    
        let contents = []
    
        function Content(title, content, sku, author, lesson) {
            this.title = title;
            this.content = content;
            this.sku = sku;
            this.author = author;
            this.lesson = lesson;
        }
        
        await rows.forEach(row => {
            let content = new Content(
                row._rawData[0],
                row._rawData[1],
                row._rawData[2],
                row._rawData[3],
                row._rawData[4]
            )
    
            contents.push(content)
        })
    
        res.json(Response.success(req, { content: contents }))
})
```

Response when calling the route:
`{"request":{"result":"success","message":""},"body":{"lessons":[]}}`

Expected response:
`{"request":{"result":"success","message":""},"body":{"content":[{"title": "Requesting Clearance","content": "some html markup text", "sku": "requesting-clearance", "author": "John D", "lesson": "test-lesson"}]}}`

Test Script does work:

```
async function getLessons() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1T8-rIN4w-T1OuYRuQ-JYI-15l9RqOXqDQ2KehWyp44E');
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
        client_email: creds.client_email,
        private_key: creds.private_key
    });
    const info = await doc.loadInfo();
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1];
    
    const rows = await sheet.getRows()
    
    rows.forEach(row => {
        printContent(row)
    })
}
async function printContent(rows) {
    let lesson = {
            title: rows._rawData[0],
            content: rows._rawData[1],
            sku: rows._rawData[2],
            author: rows._rawData[3],
            lesson: rows._rawData[4]
        };
    console.log(lesson)
}
```

Comment: When I saw your script, I thought that the script retrieves the values from 2nd sheet. So, about `It works for sheet 1 but not for sheet 2.`, I cannot understand it. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can I ask you about the value of `contents` of `It works for sheet 1`? And, can you provide your expected sample value of `contents` from your 2nd sheet?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry should have explained that better. I use a similar function for sheet 1 which works as expected. So sheet 1 is the Lessons sheet in the copy of the google sheet itself and sheet 2 is the Content sheet. I'll edit the post to add the expected sample value of `contents` now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. When I saw your updated question, your expected value is `"body":{"content":[{"title": "Requesting Clearance","content": "some html markup text", "sku": "requesting-clearance", "author": "John D", "lesson": "test-lesson"}]}`. But, it seems that your current value is `"body":{"lessons":[]}`. When I saw your script, I cannot find the key of `lessons`. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike Thats the thing, I have no idea why it's doing that. I run the code, go to the route and it gives me that. So the flow which it should be doing is 1. Log-in to the google service account to access the google sheet, 2. read the rows of the google sheet, 3. for each row it takes the data, makes it into an object and pushes it to an array with all the data in it, 4. returns the array with all the data in it along with the defaut API response. What it's doing, I have no clue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, your script is only your showing script. And, when you run your showing script, the value with the key of `lessons` is returned. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes, that is correct. Except there is more script, but it is irrelevant to the question and it is not being run when I call on the specified route.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `Yes, that is correct. Except there is more script, but it is irrelevant to the question and it is not being run when I call on the specified route.`, if your showing script returns the value with the key of `lessons`, I think that it is required to also include the key of `lessons` in your showing script. But, your showing script doesn't include the key of `lessons`. How about this? And, I deeply apologize that I cannot imagine your whole script from your question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike No worries, its really confusing. I don't know why or how or where it gets the key of ```lessons```.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when you use a simple script for retrieving the values from 2nd sheet from Google Spreadsheet, what result will you obtain? How about testing the script using a simple script? When the simple script returns `{"content":[{"title": "Requesting Clearance","content": "some html markup text", "sku": "requesting-clearance", "author": "John D", "lesson": "test-lesson"}]}` you expect, the script is included in your application. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike It seems to not be able to read from the second sheet. It just returns an empty array

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It seems to not be able to read from the second sheet. It just returns an empty array`, can you add the simple script you tested in your question? Because, when I tested your showing script, the values are retrieved from 2nd tab. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike Now the test script does seem to work... 
```async function getLessons() {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1T8-rIN4w-T1OuYRuQ-JYI-15l9RqOXqDQ2KehWyp44E');
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
        client_email: creds.client_email,
        private_key: creds.private_key
    });
    const info = await doc.loadInfo();
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[1];
    
    const rows = await sheet.getRows()
    
    rows.forEach(row => {
        printContent(row)
    })
}```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `It seems to not be able to read from the second sheet. It just returns an empty array` and `Now the test script does seem to work`. And, if you show your script, I would like to recommend adding it to your question. Because when the script is put to the comment, the readability becomes low.

Comment: @Tanaike It did not work at first, but after running it again it executes correctly. I don't know why it didnt work the first time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: @Tanaike No, the issue is not resolved. The testing script works, not the actual API script that will return the values along with the api response

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `No, the issue is not resolved. The testing script works, not the actual API script that will return the values along with the api response`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your situation. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my own answer. For some reason the `contents` array was being cleared after the `.push` and thus returned an empty array.